# Не обновляется ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `ObservableCollection<Quantity>`, и есть `ListView`, который бандит элементы из этой самой коллекции. Дальше, есть метод, в котором происходит следующая штука:

```
Resistances = new ObservableCollection<Quantity>(newList);
```

где `Resistances` - это объект `ObservableCollection<Quantity>`, связанный с `ListView`. Так вот проблема: `ListView` не хочет обновляться после этого, хотя, вроди-как, произошла замена коллекции и `ListView` должен был бы перерисоваться.

P.S. Вот так, например, работает. `ListView` корректно обновляется:

```
Resistances.Clear();
foreach (Quantity q in newList)
{
    Resistances.Add(q);
}
```

Так почему же не работает первый вариант - при замене всего списка? Разве не происходит событие `CollectionChanged`?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged реализован в том классе, где свойство Resistance находится? Ну или свойство должно быть зависимым - DependencyProperty.

Comment: @SpawnDDR хмм... не совсем понял Вас. `Resistances` - это объект `ObservableCollection<T>`, который по умолчанию реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Попробую объяснить еще раз: при изменении коллекции `Resistances` (удалении/добавлении элементов) `ListView` корректно обновляется. А вот при подмене всей коллекции - нет. Вопрос: в чем соль?

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, ваше свойство `Resistances` не бросает событие `PropertyChanged`. Для того, чтобы обновление данных сработало нужно, чтобы ваше свойство выглядело примерно так:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        if (_items != value)
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Да, вы верно поняли. У Вас получается примерно следующее:

1. Вы создаете свойство-коллекцю и привязываете его к ListView
2. Вы создаете новую коллекцию и присваиваете ее свойству, однако привязка не обновляется, т.к. формально ваше свойство не изменилось (не было брошено PropertyChanged).

Я предпочитаю использовать ленивую инициализацию коллекций без setter'ов (возможно, вам такой подход будет интересен):

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return _items ?? (_items = new ObservableCollection<string>()); }
}
private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
```

А потом очищать и заполнять ее данными.

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` в классе, объект которого содержит эти `ObservableCollection<T>` элементы, и уже из него вызывать `OnPropertyChanged("Items");`? Я правильно Вас понял? P.S. дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Да. Я обновил ответ. Посмотрите.

Answer (score 2):

ListView не знает о том, что коллекция заменена. Нужно вызвать OnPropertyChanged('Resistances') или другой способ дернуть событие PropertyChanged.

Comment: Разве при замене всей коллекции не происходит событие `CollectionChanged`: _'Происходит, когда элемент добавлен, удален, изменен или перемещен, **а также после обновлении всего списка.**'_ - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/ms653375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @AlexD. это событие самой коллекции и "обновление всего списка" имеет отношение к конкретному экземпляру коллекции. Вы же выбрасываете текущий экземпляр и присваиваете свойству новый экземпляр. P.S. MSDN не всегда точен бывает, кстати.

Comment: @AlexD.: «Обновление всего списка» — это что-то типа `Collection.Clear(); Collection.Add(item1); CollectionAdd(item2);`.

Comment: @andreycha спасибо, разобрался!